# ValueError: Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis attempting to replicate a column value between 2 disparate collectons

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to link two disparate collections using a common attribute that is "unique" to both collections.  I've validated that the attribute is unique (within the actual data, not example below). I want to use the link to assign a value in one collection to the other where it is not associated.

This is an example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd

sub_list = [{"uniqueId": "123460", "ref_idx": 1},
            {"uniqueId": "123457", "ref_idx": 2},
            {"uniqueId": "123458", "ref_idx": 3},
            {"uniqueId": "123456", "ref_idx": 3},
            {"uniqueId": "123459", "ref_idx": 4},
            {"uniqueId": "113456", "ref_idx": 4},
            {"uniqueId": "123456", "ref_idx": 6}]

primary_list = [{"uniqueId": "123456"},
                {"uniqueId": "123457"},
                {"uniqueId": "123460"},
                {"uniqueId": "123481"},
                {"uniqueId": "123461"},
                {"uniqueId": "123462"},
                {"uniqueId": "113456"},
                {"uniqueId": "123464"},
                {"uniqueId": "123456"}]

subset_df = pd.Dataframe(sub_list)
primary_df = pd.Dataframe(primary_list)
subset_df.sort_values(by="uniqueId", inplace=True)
primary_df.sort_values(by="uniqueId", inplace=True)
primary_df.set_index("uniqueId")
subset_df.set_index("uniqueId")

print("subset_df:", subset_df)
print("primary_df:", primary_df)

primary_df["ref_idx"] = subset_df.loc[subset_df["uniqueId"].eq(primary_df["uniqueId"]), ["ref_idx"]]
print("new primary_df:", primary_df)

RESULTS:

subset_df:     ref_idx uniqueId
5        4   113456
3        3   123456
6        6   123456
1        2   123457
2        3   123458
4        4   123459
0        1   123460
primary_df:    uniqueId
7   113456
0   123456
1   123457
3   123459
2   123460
5   123461
6   123462
8   123464
4   123481
new primary_df:   uniqueId  ref_idx
7   113456      NaN
0   123456      NaN
9   123456      NaN
1   123457      2.0
3   123459      4.0
2   123460      NaN
5   123461      NaN
6   123462      NaN
8   123464      NaN
4   123481      NaN
```

So this code works partially.  But it appears that the sort does not retain the row such that the `ref_idx` value is available for the assignment. The example where `uniqueId = "113456"`.

Also, when attempting to run this code on the real dataset I'm getting a `"ValueError": cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.  Which I would have thought would be related to the `uniqueId` or even the `ref_idx` value, but in the code example above I cannot reproduce that error with duplicate values in each (`uniqueId=123456`).  I've deliberately created duplicates and set the index to `uniqueId` and I would presume that since there are duplicates in my example it would error. But it does not. So what is it that I'm missing.

Suggestions?

Comment: From your first paragraph, it sounds like what you are trying to do is merge the two datasets on `uniqueId` to bring columns from the 'subset df' into the 'primary df'. Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but if that is the case, why not use `pandas.DataFrame.merge`?

Comment: Brendan, thanks for the suggestion.  My issue is that I need to retain all values in the primary_df such that if they are not identified in the subset_df the ref_idx field will have a null value.  perhaps one could rebuild the primary_df by combining the original with the merged but that seems like too many steps.

Comment: Brendan, after further review, if I use how="outer" that appears to work.  I will mark answer as correct.  Thank you!

Comment: You likely want `left` rather than `outer`, as `outer` will add all `UniqueId` from the subset dataframe even if they are not present in the primary dataframe.

Comment: Given this seems to address the question, I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that merge with how="outer" will place the newly desired attribute on the dataframe where those rows not in the subset_df will have a null value.  Thanks Brendan for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer using `merge`:

```
sub_list = [{"uniqueId": "123460", "ref_idx": 1},
            {"uniqueId": "123457", "ref_idx": 2},
            {"uniqueId": "123458", "ref_idx": 3},
            {"uniqueId": "123456", "ref_idx": 3},
            {"uniqueId": "123459", "ref_idx": 4},
            {"uniqueId": "113456", "ref_idx": 4},
            {"uniqueId": "123456", "ref_idx": 6}]

primary_list = [{"uniqueId": "123456"},
                {"uniqueId": "123457"},
                {"uniqueId": "123460"},
                {"uniqueId": "123481"},
                {"uniqueId": "123461"},
                {"uniqueId": "123462"},
                {"uniqueId": "113456"},
                {"uniqueId": "123464"},
                {"uniqueId": "123456"}]

subset_df = pd.DataFrame(sub_list)
primary_df = pd.DataFrame(primary_list)

new_df = primary_df.merge(subset_df, how='left', on='uniqueId')
```

yields

```
   uniqueId  ref_idx
0    123456      3.0
1    123456      6.0
2    123457      2.0
3    123460      1.0
4    123481      NaN
5    123461      NaN
6    123462      NaN
7    113456      4.0
8    123464      NaN
9    123456      3.0
10   123456      6.0
```

Note that as per the comment above, you likely want to merge using `how='left'` to keep the same set of `UniqueId`s as in the primary dataframe. If you want your new dataframe to have *all* `UniqueId`s, rather than only those in the primary dataframe, you can use `how='outer'`.